# Lock/unlock cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba, locking

I have been looking for a code to lock all the cells in a sheet but one  and I found this code:

```
Worksheets("SW").Range("D2").Locked = False
Worksheets("SW").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

it really worked fine until I saved it and closed/opened the file again, then any macros I had were  run.

I guess it is because in that sheet I have different macros and also I have the macro that runs when a cell is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

One more thing, this workbook it will be shared, so I don't know that will affect the macros.

sorry maybe I was too ambiguous.

Yes I want to prevent others to change de value of the cells.

I want that just one cell could be changed so all the others are changing with the macros.

Thanks again for all your help

PS: yes  Ahmad Al-Mutawa, I want to be impossible to chang the sheet even after the project being saved, closed and opened.

If you need more info just tell me I'll try to be more specific.

Comment: I think you forgot half of your explaination ;)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Do you want to prevent people from changing the sheet even after saving closing/re-opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your file have any macros doing other operations than this lock unlock code you are trying to achieve?

If so I suggest you having a code in vba. Otherwise you can simply lock the sheets to prevent users from changing somethings or anytime at all without a code.

do you think this could be better for you than a [code][1]?

[ http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-HA010096837.aspx ][1]

Out of curiosity: BY ANY CHANCE are you having an issue not knowing where and how to trigger this code piece?

**Edited code:-**
Your comment is not clear, nonethless I believe you want to use a macro.
Assuming you want to protect/lock or unprotect/unlock Sheet1, please try the following. :-

Add this code in Workbook open event in thisworkbook:-

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim shtSheet As Worksheet
  Dim strPassword As String

    strPassword = "stack"
    Set shtSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    shtSheet.Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Next add the following in your module. And call it after you finish running your macro.

```
 Sub ProtectSheet()
  Dim shtSheet As Worksheet
  Dim strPassword As String

     strPassword = "stack"
     Set shtSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
     shtSheet.Protect strPassword
 End Sub
```

Comment: yes, that is the problem, I run macros that change the values of the cells locked, so I need some code to sort it out. I thought that maybe with my upper code it could work, and it dit it until I closed and opened again.

Comment: no, that is not my problem, the problem is that my macros dont run when I locked the sheet, just run the first time, when the workbook is closed and opened is when the problem appear. sorry, maybe my english is not so clear, but I wish I could explain it better, sorry and thanks

Comment: Sorry that I was unable to understand your question. Perhas the title is misleading. Let's change this code a bit: you can put the first unprotect code piece within your Workbook open event with UserInterfaceOnly to true. 

Then add Protect sub into the end of your main module. When your macros are completed, sheet will be protected fully.
I have edited the code.